# Google logins from unknown device/location

Tags: gmail

A few months ago, I forgot to log out of my google/gmail account from a "friend's" Samsung Galaxy Tablet. I noticed shortly after that, there was a login to my account from a device..a Samsung Galaxy Tablet.

I have never owned a tablet. I asked this person to please log out assuming it was in fact them, as the ip location for the login was unavailable. They stated they never logged into my account. Since then, I have seen logins from a Linux Device, no IP address, but the location is not the same as mine for my phone or my computer. I have changed all my passwords (more than once) as well as set up 2 step verification, but these logins from a Linux device are still showing.

I was asleep the last few times the logins occurred. How do I get to the bottom of this, or how do I get these logins to stop?

Comment: Change your password.

Comment: You can force log out of every client, once you do that, change the password.  Questions about Google Accounts strickly speaking are not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: "If you've forgotten to sign out of your email on another computer, you can sign out of your other Gmail sessions by going to the bottom right corner of Gmail, clicking Details, and then Sign out all other web sessions." from https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154?hl=en